# IntelliJ LibGDX Error "org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated"

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been trying to run an application for LibGDX. I followed the steps from https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Running%20and%20Debugging.html#running-br-br-. I made the configuration an application, the main class is the desktop launcher, working directory is is andriod assets(since I couldn't find the core/assets), and I made the JRE desktop not desktop main because it would make an error and not show the results I need, it shows, "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener". Following the steps I did after android assets, I tried to run the program, and it says, "org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated". I tried looking it up, but nothing shows.